# Start bxSlider based on url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my [bXslider](http://bxslider.com/options) slide to change based on the hash in the url on load. 
If my url is www.website.com/#slide1 it should show the first slide and if my url is www.website.com/#slide2 it should show the second slide.

I was able to make it work by using this jQuery code:

```
if(typeof $.fn.bxSlider !== "undefined"){
            var mainSlider = $('#homepage .bxslider').bxSlider({
                mode:'fade',
                pager: true,
            });
            if(location.hash === "#slide1") {
                mainSlider.goToSlide(1);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide2"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(2);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide3"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(3);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide4"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(4);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide5"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(5);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide6"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(6);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide7"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(7);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide8"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(8);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide9"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(9);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide10"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(10);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide11"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(11);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide12"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(12);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide13"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(13);
            } else if(location.hash === "#slide14"){
                mainSlider.goToSlide(14);
            } 
        }
```

The problem is, it only works when the hash is #slide1 or #slide2. Is there something wrong with my code? Is there shorter way of doing this?

Also, I used the code below to add different id's to all my .bx-pager-item elements:

```
$('#pagination .bx-pager-item').each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'slide'+(i+1));
});
```

How do I add the id as a hash to the end of the href so that when you click on the first .bx-pager-item element with the id of slide1 it will take you to another page with the hash of #slide1 at the end of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, it only works when the hash #1 and #2. Is there
>   something wrong with my code? Is there shorter way of doing this?

[The documentation](http://bxslider.com/options) says you can pass the `startSlide` option when you instantiate the slider. Hence, your code could look something like this:

```
if (typeof $.fn.bxSlider !== "undefined") {

  // Check if '#slide' is present in the hash.
  // Replace it with an empty string so we have whatever comes after left.
  // Convert that to an integer for the startSlide option

  var slideId = (location.hash.indexOf('#slide') > -1) ? parseInt(location.hash.replace('#slide', ''), 10) : null;

  if (slideId) {

    $('#homepage .bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode:'fade',
      pager: true,
      startSlide: slideId - 1,
    });

  }

}
```

It's not completely bulletproof though. You could add more checks to make sure someone won't succeed in entering `#slide10abc`. [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will not throw a proper index your way in that case :)

> How do I add the id as a hash to the end of the href so that when you
>   click on the first .bx-pager-item element with the id of slide1 it
>   will take you to another page with the hash of #slide1 at the end of
>   the URL?

I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you'd be able to do something like this depending on the HTML that you're looping over:

```
$('#pagination .bx-pager-item').each(function(i) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var currentHref = $this.attr('href');
   var newHref = currentHref + '/#slide' + (i+1);
   $this.attr('href', newHref);
});
```

Again, you could do some checks to make sure that what you set as new href is actually valid/proper URLs. E.g. check for '/' at the end of the current href, thus avoiding adding that twice.

Hope the above will get you closer to your goal. If not please ask for further explanation in the comments.

---

**Answer to comment: Combining the two pieces of code in a callback**

````
If you want to manipulate the slides after bxSlider is loaded, you could use the ```onSliderLoad``` callback, which is passed to the options object for the slider. It would look something like this:

if (typeof $.fn.bxSlider !== "undefined") {

  var slideId = (location.hash.indexOf('#slide') > -1) ? parseInt(location.hash.replace('#slide', ''), 10) : null;

  if (slideId) {

    $('#homepage .bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode:'fade',
      pager: true,
      startSlide: slideId - 1,
      onSliderLoad: function() {
        $('#pagination .bx-pager-item').each(function(i) {
           var $this = $(this);
           var currentHref = $this.attr('href');
           var newHref = currentHref + '/#slide' + (i+1);
           $this.attr('href', newHref);
        });
      }
    });

  }

}
````

Comment: Thanks. It worked! There's a callback option in the bXslider. How do I use that to make it function they I want it to?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Was that what you meant? :)